# Feature selection from large time series data

Tags: time-series, feature-selection, high-dimensional

I have a dataset containing thousands of economic variables (FRED data) and I am looking to algorithmic-ally extract a set of leading indicators to be used in a forecasting framework.

1. Granger causality seems the most obvious test for determining which variables are leading indicators but I am concerned this will be computationally intractable as it would require estimating and determining lag order for 2n models. Is there a more efficient way to estimate causality across such a wide range of features?
2. Beyond using granger causality are there any other methods that come to mind for selecting leading indicators from such a large dataset?

Thanks for any thoughts or suggestions!!

Comment: The classical econometric technique for this task seems to be dynamic factor analysis.

Comment: Thanks Max I think DFM would be more appropriate for feature extraction. In this case I’m looking more for feature selection. I want to maintain the original features just find an algorithmic way to reduce the universe of features to only those that may be leading indicators.

Comment: You could do worse than a penalised VAR model; using a sparsity-inducing penalty like the LASSO will allow you to reduce the number of parameters to be estimated and it performs estimation and variable selection simultaneously.

Comment: Were you able to find any methods? I am exactly in the same quest. I have more than 100 variables and want to do feature selection.

Comment: So it's not ideal but the computational complexity of the Granger causality was actually not terrible so I was able to solve my problem with that. I also used a lasso regression as a robustness test and both provided a similar feature set. It should be noted as an aside that with that many tests you are likely to deal with false discovery so managing that will be important. There are some p-value correction processes you can use like FDR and Bonferroni. In my case, it wasn't ideal as I wanted to cast a wide net but should be noted.